# Run controller only first time tab was clicked - AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm developing a website for our company, and one of the pages contains several tabs :

[image]

I want the loading operation to be done for each tab only once and not every time I click it, because these tabs have some API calls, and reloading takes time.

What is the best way to do it? I'm using Ui-router and ui-sref to move between each tab :

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="list-group panel panel-default">

                <a ui-sref="dashboards.firstTab" ui-sref-active="active" class="list-group-item" id="firstTab_button">
                    <i style="color:darkblue" class="fa fa-area-chart"></i>&nbsp; TAB1 </a>

                <a ui-sref="dashboards.secondTab" ui-sref-active="active" class="list-group-item" id="secondTab_button">
                    <i style="color:darkblue" class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>&nbsp; TAB2 </a>

                <a ui-sref="dashboards.thirdTab" ui-sref-active="active" class="list-group-item" id="thirdTab_button">
                    <i style="color:darkblue" class="fa fa-server"></i>&nbsp; TAB3 </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




<div ui-view class="col-xs-12">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="vm.isTabOneSelected">
                    <div ng-include src="'components/Cards/Tabs/TabOne/TabOne.html'"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="vm.isTabTwoSelected">
                    <div ng-include src="'components/Cards/Tabs/TabTwo/TabTwo.html'"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="vm.isTabThreeSelected">
                    <graph-panel  panel-title="TabThree {{vm.isTabThreeSelected}}" chart-config="vm.charts.TabOneChartSite"></graph-panel>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Each Controller, You can cache your loaded data in a service, and when you load your controller you will start by checking this service if it does not have the data, then you will request it from your APIs , in this case you only request your data once you access the tab for the first time :

eg. your service

```
app.service('dataService', function() {

    this.firstTabData =  null;

    this.getFirstTabData = function () {
        return this.firstTabData;
    };

    this.setFirstTabData = function (data) {
        this.firstTabData = data;
    };
});
```

your controller

```
app.controller('tabOne', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.load = function () {
        if(dataService.getFirstTabData()) {
            $scope.data = dataService.getFirstTabData();
        }
        else {
            $scope.data = getDataFromAPI();
        }

    };

    var getDataFromAPI = function () {
         //get your data 

         dataService.setFirstTabData(dataFromAPI);
    };


});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion, let me check this option, if it works well i'll mark this as resolved so other people will be able to use this method.